# Url.Action is encoding parameter values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

In ASP.NET MVC, if I use:

> <% Response.Write(Url.Action("Index",
>   "usermanagement", new
>   RouteValueDictionary(new { page =
>   "{0}" }))); %>

I get:

/usermanagement?page=%7B0%7D

But I wanted to get:

/usermanagement?page={0}

Why is it encondig my parameter value, and what should I do to write the parameter value unencoded?

Thank you

Comment: if you're using JavaScript to do the replacement, you could just escape the JavaScript string too. ex: url = url.replace(escape('{0}'), pagenumber)

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514440/how-to-leave-url-parameters-unescaped-in-asp-net-mvc) worked for me.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The `Url.Action` helper method is used to generate urls. Urls need to be URL encoded for them to be valid urls. So what you are observing is perfectly normal behavior. The helper generates a valid url by encoding all parameters.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that {0} is a placeholder. I'll replace that bit with the actual page number. I've changed the placeholder to something else (_PAGE_) so that it doesn't get encoded. There should be an option to encode or not the URL parameters.

Comment: -1 Thanks for stating the obvious but the OP's question remains unanswered

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid QueryString params if possible. Turn them into route parameters. Next, curly braces should be escaped and that's what the Url.Action() helper is doing for you.

Comment: This probably is what he meant to do, he wants to build up a URL using routing, but apply the route values on the client