# Unformat Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to build url with the UrlHelper and some Angular variable inside. Is there a classy trick to avoid URL.Action from escaping `{` and `}` ?

Current code :

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { productId = "{{model.productId}}" };
```

Actual output :

```
/Home/Index/?productId=%7B%7Bmodel.productId%7D%7D
```

Desired one :

```
 /Home/Index/?productId={{model.productId}}
```

Or should I go through a dirty `string.Format` and `MvcHtmlString` ?

Edit :

This is not working

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { productId = new MvcHtmlString("{{model.productId}}") };
```

Comment: Try this: `@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { productId = "{{model.productId}}" })`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514440/how-to-leave-url-parameters-unescaped-in-asp-net-mvc for alternative solutions.