# Urlhelper.action encodes some special characters

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-core, urlencode, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.Net Core web api.
I use the IUrlHelper.Action to generate a fully qualified URL. 
When I pass

Østjylland - Copy%*

It escapes the Ø and the whitespaces but not the *

%C3%98stjylland%20-%20copy*

Acording to the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_15

No characters should be escaped. Why does this happen? Do I really have to use WebUtility to first decode the url from UrlHelper and then encode it again with WebUtility to escape all the special characters?

Comment: Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514440/how-to-leave-url-parameters-unescaped-in-asp-net-mvc) worked for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514440/how-to-leave-url-parameters-unescaped-in-asp-net-mvc) worked for me.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionNoEscape(this HtmlHelper html, string actionName, string controllerName, object values)
{
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(values);
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes);
    string url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName);
    url += "?";
    List<string> paramList = new List<string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in routeValues)
    {
        object value = pair.Value ?? "";
        paramList.Add(string.Concat(pair.Key, "=", Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    }
    url += string.Join("&", paramList.ToArray());
    return new MvcHtmlString(url);
}
```

Granted, I'm working in .NET Framework, but the concepts should be the same for .NET Core. Hope this helps!